# postgres schema not found when create with upper case

Tags: postgresql, openjpa

I am trying to create app using OpenJPA & Postgres 9.2.xx, Currently facing issue at DB level

1) Created schema say PCM:-

```
CREATE SCHEMA PCM
```

2) Tried create table :-

```
CREATE TABLE PCM.USER_PROFILE (
USER_PROFILE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
USER_FNAME VARCHAR(60),
USER_LNAME VARCHAR(60)
};
```

Got error "pcm" schema does not exists

Then tried creating table :-

```
CREATE TABLE "PCM.USER_PROFILE" (
USER_PROFILE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
USER_FNAME VARCHAR(60),
USER_LNAME VARCHAR(60)
};
```

Table is created successful, 
If I list the schema:-

```
[postgres@DBMigration ~] $ psql -c "\dn"

  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 pcm    | dbadmin
 public | postgres
```

B) In persistence.xml , I have entered configuration

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="PCM" />
```

Now I am getting issue in OpenJPA stating schema is not present.

I tried refering [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/42D4C41C.3090502@joops.com), but no success.

I have tried entering schema name in configuration as `'\"PCM\"', "\"PCM\"", '\"pcm\"', "\"pcm\""`.

Not sure where am I going wrong.

I need suggestion/help, 
1) how or what is proper standard to create schema in Postgres & refer while creating table.

2) Is my entry in persistence.xml correct? Then why its not identifying the schema

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object names in Postgres when not quoted are implicitly converted to lower case.

When you create a table the way you did below with quotation mark on `"PCM.USER_PROFILE"` then the table is created in default `public` schema with the name of `"PCM.USER_PROFILE"`.

```
CREATE TABLE "PCM.USER_PROFILE" (
  USER_PROFILE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  USER_FNAME VARCHAR(60),
  USER_LNAME VARCHAR(60)
);
```

However, your create statement mentioned in the post is completely valid (with the exception of changing `}` to `)` at the end of command:

```
CREATE TABLE PCM.USER_PROFILE (
  USER_PROFILE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  USER_FNAME VARCHAR(60),
  USER_LNAME VARCHAR(60)
);
```

It creates `user_profile` table under `pcm` schema succesfully.

Comment: Thank for correction about the typo error changing } to ).  Now I tried creating table   CREATE TABLE PCM.USER_PROFILE (
  USER_PROFILE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  USER_FNAME VARCHAR(60),
  USER_LNAME VARCHAR(60)
);  ERROR:  schema "pcm" does not exist

Comment: I followed your create statements and it all works fine for me. Are you sure your schema exists? Are you running these queries directly from `psql`?

Comment: Thank you Kamil G, yeah I had missed that point. Sorry I did not see your latest comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added clarification about tablename. By mentioning the schema `public` I thought it might be obvious, but indeed - it isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error that I did was created schema outside database environment & root user. When we tried running `select * from information_schema.schemata;` under both users (root & db user) the schema was not listing.

Hence create schema under a DB by running query

```
psql -U [dbUser] -d [database] -c "CREATE SCHEMA pcm;"
```

or

```
psql -h localhost -U [dbUser] -d [database]
[database]#=>  CREATE SCHEMA pcm;
```

Try running query to test if schema is loaded successfully under database & dbowner user.

```
[database]#=> select * from information_schema.schemata;
```